# Unit Test Xml encoding issue

Tags: c#, xml, unit-testing, encoding

Consider following class:

```
public class SampleXmlGenerator
{
    public byte[] GenerateDocumentBytes()
    {
        byte[] fileBytes;
        using (var xmlStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(xmlStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8")))
            {
                myWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                myWriter.Indentation = 4;
                myWriter.IndentChar = ' ';
                myWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                myWriter.WriteStartElement("foo");
                myWriter.WriteString("bar");
                myWriter.WriteEndElement(); // end foo

                myWriter.Flush();

                fileBytes = xmlStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return fileBytes;
    }
}
```

With following Unit Test:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestSampleXmlGenerator
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TextEmptyDocument()
    {
        var actualBytes = new SampleXmlGenerator().GenerateDocumentBytes();
        var actualUtf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(actualBytes);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("// actualUtf8String");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(actualUtf8String);

        var actualDefaultString = Encoding.Default.GetString(actualBytes);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("// actualDefaultString");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(actualDefaultString);


        var expectedString = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<foo>bar</foo>";
        var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(expectedString);

//      var expectedBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
//<foo>bar</foo>"));
//      var expectedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(expectedBytes);

        Console.Out.WriteLine("// expectedString");
        Console.Out.WriteLine(expectedString);

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedBytes.Length, actualBytes.Length);
        //Assert.AreEqual(expectedString, actualUtf8String);
    }
}
```

And finally output:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<54>. Actual:<57>. 

// actualUtf8String
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>bar</foo>

// actualDefaultString
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>bar</foo>

// expectedString
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>bar</foo>
```

`expectedString` and `actualUtf8String` look the same, but are not.

`actualDefaultString` shows the 3 extra chars at the beginning.

So what gives? How do I go about testing/comparing generated XML? What should I do differently?

Comment: There is a constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s064f8w2(v=vs.110).aspx to eliminate the byte order mark.

Comment: Thanks Martin, but I did not want to eliminate BOM from document, just during testing ignore it. But your link did point me in the right direction, and what to look for.

Comment: why not make a Test function that checks the BOM and returns the rest as a string?

Comment: Can you show me what you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are seeing is BOM preamble

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble(v=vs.110).aspx

you can either test for it, or not serialize it.

Comment: I ended up removing in the Unit Test, as I did not want to change Xml generation process.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions from Martin and Keith, and with some additional research I ended up removing BOM from generated XML bytes in Unit Test, in following manner (based on following [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317700/strip-byte-order-mark-from-string-in-c-sharp)):

```
        var xmlBytes = new SampleXmlGenerator().GenerateDocumentBytes();
        var newXmlDoc = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};
        newXmlDoc.Load(new MemoryStream(xmlBytes));
        var actualBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newXmlDoc.OuterXml);
```

Now Unit Test passes!