# UTF-8 Byte Mark check gives different value based on operating system

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

We have some unit-tests that are checking UTF-8 byte marking of an XML string before it's loaded into an XmlDocument. Everything works fine using Windows 7 64-bit, but we noticed a bunch of tests failing while trying to run under Windows 10 64-bit.

After a bit of investigation, we found that the XML string on Windows 10 is getting pruned (the preamble exists), while on Windows 7 it does not.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 public static string PruneUtf8ByteMark(string xmlString)
    {
        var byteOrderMarking = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
        if (xmlString.StartsWith(byteOrderMarking))
        {
            xmlString = xmlString.Remove(0, byteOrderMarking.Length);
        }

        return xmlString;
    }
```

`StartsWith` is returning **true** for Windows 10, and **false** for Windows 7. Note that the same XML string is being used, the only difference here is the OS.

Any ideas? We are a bit lost here, since both PCs are x64 running the same .NET version.

**edit:**
The string comes from a class via:

```
public static string XmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"....
```

On Windows 10, the less than sign gets truncated because the byte mark check is true.

Comment: What does the string come from?

Comment: @SLaks the string comes from dummy test data. It's an XML string that's wrapped in a class and accessible via public static.

Comment: hard to believe if that string is not read from a file. which value does the debugger show for `byteOrderMarking` in either case?

Comment: You should use `StringComparison.Ordinal` in the second argument of StartWith to avoid culture based comparison.

Comment: @dlatikay, yeah definitely not from a file. the mask (preamble) shows EF BB BF, but the GetString of it shows "" for both OSs.

Comment: @Kalten, I'll definitely add that. thanks

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4900684 the way it is identified as whitespace and trimmed, but that would also imply a different framework version or culture setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is cause by culture sensitive comparison.

The byteOrderMarking is not a visible character so it will be trimmed during comparison.

See the following case :

```
"".StartsWith("") // = true
"aa".StartsWith("") // = true 
"aa".StartsWith("", StringComparison.Ordinal) // = true
```

So every string start with an empty string. Now with byteOrderMarking :

```
var byteOrderMarking = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
byteOrderMarking.Equals("") // = False
byteOrderMarking.Equals("", StringComparison.CurrentCulture) // = True
byteOrderMarking.Equals("", StringComparison.Ordinal) // = False
```

Now we can see that byteOrderMarking is equal to an empty string only with Current culture comparison. When you try to check is a string start with byteOrderMarking, it's like to compare to an an empty string.

The difference between Ordinal and CurrentCulture is that the first is a byte to byte comparison, whereas the second will by normalize according to the culture.

Lastly, I suggest to always use Ordinal (or OrdinalIgnoreCase) to compare technical strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I understand why to use Ordinal, but I still do not understand why the string comparison then is different across OS versions.

Comment: In win10 they add many more new supported languages. That can be related. The .Net framework depend often on windows api. So if the os change, the framework could be affected.