# Is there a way to remove the BOM from a UTF-8 encoded file? 

Tags: ruby, byte-order-mark

Is there a way to remove the BOM from a UTF-8 encoded file?

I know that all of my JSON files are encoded in UTF-8, but the data entry person who edited the JSON files saved it as UTF-8 with the BOM.

When I run my Ruby scripts to parse the JSON, it is failing with an error.
I don't want to manually open 58+ JSON files and convert to UTF-8 without the BOM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid tripping over UTF-8 BOM when reading files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543225/how-to-avoid-tripping-over-utf-8-bom-when-reading-files)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So, the solution was to do a search and replace on the BOM via gsub!
I forced the encoding of the string to UTF-8 and also forced the regex pattern to be encoded in UTF-8.

I was able to derive a solution by looking at http://self.d-struct.org/195/howto-remove-byte-order-mark-with-ruby-and-iconv and http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string

```
def read_json_file(file_name, index)
  content = ''
  file = File.open("#{file_name}\\game.json", "r") 
  content = file.read.force_encoding("UTF-8")

  content.gsub!("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8"), '')

  json = JSON.parse(content)

  print json
end
```

Comment: I would recommend `sub!(/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/, '')` as the BOM occures only once at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I would actually suggest `String#delete!` over `String#gsub!(..., '')`

Comment: @Jan your suggestion is good unless your setup is defaulting to UTF-8 or at least that's what I believe to be my problem because your command does not work on mine.  Just doing `content.sub!(/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/, '')` gives an "invalid UTF-8 byte sequence" error.

Comment: @Ryan I think @Jan simply meant using `sub` instead of `gsub`, but didn't necessarily mean to drop the `force_encoding`.

Answer (score 42):

With ruby >= 1.9.2 you can use the mode `r:bom|utf-8`

This should work (I haven't test it in combination with json):

```
json = nil #define the variable outside the block to keep the data
File.open('file.txt', "r:bom|utf-8"){|file|
  json = JSON.parse(file.read)
}
```

It doesn't matter, if the BOM is available in the file or not.

---

Andrew remarked, that `File#rewind` can't be used with BOM.

If you need a rewind-function you must remember the position and replace `rewind` with `pos=`:

```
#Prepare test file
File.open('file.txt', "w:utf-8"){|f|
  f << "\xEF\xBB\xBF" #add BOM
  f << 'some content'
}

#Read file and skip BOM if available
File.open('file.txt', "r:bom|utf-8"){|f|
  pos =f.pos
  p content = f.read  #read and write file content
  f.pos = pos   #f.rewind  goes to pos 0
  p content = f.read  #(re)read and write file content
}
```

Comment: one-liner for ruby (takes file paths on STDIN): `ruby -ne 'File.open($_.strip, "r:bom|utf-8") {|f| content=f.read(f.size); f.close; File.open($_.strip, "w").write(content) }`

Comment: So this failed for me because I used File#rewind. At least in ruby 1.9.2, using "bom|UTF-8" simply advances the file pointer when you open it, and this gets forgotten when you rewind. Seems to me like a poor implementation of open given this encoding parameter.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz You are right. I extended my answer with a work around for your problem.

Answer (score 13):

You can also specify encoding with the `File.read` and `CSV.read` methods, but you don't  specify the `read` mode.

```
File.read(path, :encoding => 'bom|utf-8')
CSV.read(path, :encoding => 'bom|utf-8')
```

Comment: it works well 10 years later

Comment: nice and clean, it just feels like the right way! also.. it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

the "bom|UTF-8" encoding works well if you only read the file once, but fails if you ever call File#rewind, as I was doing in my code. To address this, I did the following:

```
def ignore_bom
  @file.ungetc if @file.pos==0 && @file.getc != "\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8")
end
```

which seems to work well. Not sure if there are other similar type characters to look out for, but they could easily be built into this method that can be called any time you rewind or open.

Answer (score 2):

Server side cleanup of utf-8 bom bytes that worked for me:

```
csv_text.gsub!("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented this for the [smarter_csv](https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv) gem, and want to share this in case someone comes across this issue.

The problem is to remove byte-sequences independent of the string encoding. The solution is to use the methods `bytes` and `byteslice` from the `String` class.

See: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#method-i-bytes

```
    UTF_8_BOM = %w[ef bb bf].freeze

    def remove_bom(str)
      str_as_hex = str.bytes.map{|x| x.to_s(16)}
      return str.byteslice(3..-1) if str_as_hex[0..2] == UTF_8_BOM

      str
    end
```