# Rails Migration Failing to Update Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I am using Rails 3.1.1 and Ruby 1.9.2. I am moving a database from a Ruby 1.8.7 environment to a Ruby 1.9 environment and would like to execute the following migration:

```
# coding: utf-8
class CleanseVerses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Poem.all.each do |vs|

      cleansed_text = String.new
      cleansed_text = vs.text

      cleansed_text.gsub!('â€”',  '—')
      cleansed_text.gsub!(' - ',  ' — ')
      cleansed_text.gsub!('â€™',  '’')
      cleansed_text.gsub!('â€œ',  '“')
      cleansed_text.gsub!('â€', '”')
      cleansed_text.gsub!('prince', 'king')

      vs.text = cleansed_text

      vs.save

    end
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

The problem is that the database doesn't seem to reflect any of the changes. Even the simple 'prince' to 'king' conversion isn't working.

I do have attr_accessible on the Poem.text field.

Am I missing something fundamental on strings?

UPDATE:

It seems that I am missing something fundamental on the nature of strings.

When I change the following two lines:

```
cleansed_text = String.new
cleansed_text = vs.text
```

to

```
cleansed_text = String.new(vs.text)
```

then everything works perfectly.

Comment: My guess is that the records are failing to save for some reason. Try changing `vs.save` to `vs.save!` so an exception will be raised if the record isn't saved.

Comment: I have tried it with save! and it wasn't raising any exceptions.

Comment: re: Update. A surprising result. I'd love to hear from someone more knowledgeable why that would occur. You're sure nothing else changed? The `String.new` shouldn't be necessary at all. If `vs.text` isn't already a string (or you're not sure), doing an explicit cast by calling `vs.text.to_s` is probably a better approach.

Comment: I'm fairly sure nothing else changed. It seems very mysterious to me too but I feel as though I've bumped into this exact issue in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
# coding: utf-8
vs = 'â€”  - â€™ â€œ â€ prince'
vs.gsub!('â€”', '—')
  .gsub!(' - ',  ' — ')
  .gsub!('â€™',  '’')
  .gsub!('â€œ',  '“')
  .gsub!('â€', '”')
  .gsub!('prince', 'king')
puts vs
```

which prints `—  — ’ “ ” king`

The bang on the end of `gsub!` indicates that it operates in place. Note that [`#gsub!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) is not the same as [`#gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) which does not modify in place.

You can perform this operation directly on `vs.text` since it's already a string and skip the whole `cleansed_text` thing entirely.

All that said, the only two reasons I can think of that your example isn't working are

1. Your changes are not being persisted because they are failing to save, and
2. Your `Poem` class doesn't have a method `text` that represents a column `text` in your `poems` table via `ActiveRecord`.

While I understand that your changes are not currently being persisted, it is generally considered to be a good idea to make your migrations reversible in the `down` method when at all possible.

If you or anyone on your team uses a Windows text editor, make sure your migration [doesn't have a byte order mark in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011504/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-encoded-file), just in case.

---

Since you mention 1.8, do read about [how things have changed](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string) in 1.9.

And since this looks like an encoding conversion, if you know the old encoding why don't you [use `String#encode`](http://blog.segment7.net/2010/12/17/from-iconv-iconv-to-string-encode)?

Comment: I updated my question but it appears that the way I was initially doing it was not actually changing the text in the 'text' column.