# Weird behaviors in matching the beginnings of lines returned by IO#read

Tags: ruby, regex

Here's what I've encountered this morning. I've got a lot of JavaScript files written in CMD pattern like this:

```
define(function(require, exports) {
    // code goes here
})
```

I've got a simple ruby script to manipulate these files for results like this:

```
define(['module-a', 'module-b'], function(reuqire, exports) {
    // code
})
```

That way I've done it is by opening these file, reading their contents, see if they match `/^define\(function/`, then replace them if they do:

```
code = File.open('foo.js').read
if code =~ /^define\(function/
  # do some work
end
```

The weird part is, the code won't match that regular expression. Line 2 returns `nil`. This will work:

```
code = "define(function(require, exports) {\n"
code =~ /^define\(function/ # ==> 0
```

It just returns `nil` if the code is read using `IO#read`. The beginning of string works however:

```
code = File.open('foo.js').read
code =~ /.define\(function/m # ==> 0

code[0] # ==> "" returns an empty string
```

But isn't `^` matching all the line beginnings?

Comment: Works for me. What does `IO#read` return?

Comment: @halfelf returns the file content successfully

Comment: With Ruby 1.9.3, works for me also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That weird string turned out to be the BOM of that text file. Some colleague of this project saved files in UTF-8, which is the encoding we agreed to use, with BOM.

Here's the solution: [Is there a way to remove the BOM from a UTF-8 encoded file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011504/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-encoded-file)

Answer (score 0):

Check for whitespace other than \n before "define"? Especially for \r . . .