# Loading data from YAML in ruby changing the encoding/byte structure of data?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, yaml, byte-order-mark

I am trying to write a method to remove some blacklisted characters like `bom` characters using their `UTF-8` values. I am successful to achieve this by creating a `method` in `String` class with the following logic,

```
  def remove_blacklist_utf_chars
    self.force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub!(config[:blacklist_utf_chars][:zero_width_space].force_encoding("UTF-8"), "")
    self
  end
```

Now to make it useful across the applications  and reusable I create a config in a `yml file`. The `yml` structure is something like,

```
:blacklist_utf_chars:
  :zero_width_space: '"\u{200b}"'
```

(**Edit**) Also as suggested by Drenmi this didn't work,

```
:blacklist_utf_chars:
  :zero_width_space: \u{200b}
```

The problem I am facing is that the method `remove_blacklist_utf_chars` does not work when I load the utf-encoding of blacklist characters from `yml file`
But when I directly pass these in the method and not via the `yml file` the method works.

So basically
`self.force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub!("\u{200b}".force_encoding("UTF-8"), "")` -- works.

but,

`self.force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub!(config[:blacklist_utf_chars][:zero_width_space].force_encoding("UTF-8"), "")` -- doesn't work.

I printed the value of `config[:blacklist_utf_chars][:zero_width_space]` and its equal to `"\u{200b}"`

I got this idea by referring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011768/2362505.

Now I am not sure how what exactly is happening when the blacklist chars list is loaded via yml in ruby code.

**EDIT 2:**

On further investigation I observed that there is an extra `\` getting added while reading the hash from the yaml.
So,

```
puts config[:blacklist_utf_chars][:zero_width_space].dump
```

prints:

```
"\\u{200b}"
```

But then if I just define the yaml as:

```
:blacklist_utf_chars:
  :zero_width_space: 200b
```

and do,

```
ch = "\u{#{config[:blacklist_utf_chars][:zero_width_space]}}"
self.force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub!(ch.force_encoding("UTF-8"), "")
```

I get

```
/Users/harshsingh/dir/to/code/utils.rb:121: invalid Unicode escape (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"\u{200b}"` syntax is used for escaping Unicode characters in *Ruby source code*. It won’t work inside *Yaml*.

The [equivalent syntax for a Yaml document](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#ns-esc-16-bit) is the similar `"\u200b"` (which also happens to be valid in Ruby). Note the lack of braces (`{}`), and also the [double quotes are required](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2776092), otherwise it will be parsed as literal `\u200b`.

So your Yaml file should look like this:

```
:blacklist_utf_chars:
  :zero_width_space: "\u200b"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `puts` the value, and get the output `"\u{200b}"`, it means the quotes are included in your string. I.e., you're actually calling:

```
self.force_encoding("UTF-8").gsub!('"\u{200b}"'.config[:blacklist_utf_chars][:zero_width_space].force_encoding("UTF-8"), "")
```

Try changing your YAML file to:

```
:blacklist_utf_chars:
  :zero_width_space: \u{200b}
```

Comment: I tried doing that but then the `yaml` get syntax error.

Comment: Sorry. Try to remove the quotes altogether. That will make it valid YAML, and hopefully fix your problem. :-)

Comment: @harshs08: Looks like the backslash is getting escaped. Let's see if we can fix that.

Comment: check the updated question, the backslash is indeed getting escaped but then how can i add the \u back to string in the code.