# In Ruby, how to reliably detect a file's encoding (including UTF-16 without BOM)?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, utf-16, utf-16le

I need to detect a file type and encoding in Ruby.

I'm currently using libmagic through the [magic](https://github.com/qoobaa/magic) gem, but it has one problem: it doesn't detect UTF-16 files if they don't have BOM. [This](https://yadi.sk/i/k5CAQ_DMHHcwYA) is an example of such file.

```
$ file -i text_without_bom.txt
text_without_bom.txt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Is there any other library or method I could use that would detect UTF-16 files properly?

P. S. Also tried [rchardet](https://github.com/jmhodges/rchardet) and [charlock_holmes](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes), without much luck.

Comment: `file` is really good at what it does, but it still has limitations.

Comment: try `puts Encoding.list` to see what you are up against.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to detect the encoding of a text file reliably. You have to be told out-of-band what the encoding is.

The reason for this is simple: there are tons of 8-bit encodings. In those encodings, *every* combination of 8 bits is a valid character. Since every combination of 8 bits is a valid character in every 8 bit encoding, *any arbitrary* text file, and in fact any arbitrary file *at all* is a valid text file in *any* 8 bit encoding.

For example, in ISO 8859-15 `0xA4` is the Euro sign `€`. In ISO 8859-1, CP1252, and Unicode, `0xA4` is the international currency sign `¤`. So, if you have a file that contains `0xA4`, you cannot know if it is ISO 8859-15, ISO 8859-1, CP1252, one half of a character in UTF-16, one quarter of a character in UTF-32, the middle of a multibyte sequence in UTF-8, or one of many other possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

You can always cut BOM off and process file without it.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011768/5162051) describes how it can be done.

Comment: The problem is, I already don't have a BOM, and without it, character detection libraries can't understand that it's UTF-16.

Comment: Is it allways UTF-16 without BOM?

Comment: No, it MIGHT be UTF-16 without BOM.

Comment: Is it always UTF-16?

Comment: No, it really might be anything.

Comment: UTF-16 file will be twice the size of UTF-8 file with the same content and each "char" will be separated by "\x00". May be we can remove all "\x00" and check if file size will match the number of letters?