# Lat/Long coordinate from an imported CSV when parsed to float turns to a 0

Tags: ruby

I have some lat/long coordinates that i've imported from a CSV file, but for some reason the first latitude value in the file when converted to a float turns to a 0, and Im not sure what to do, everything says the encoding is utf8 when i test the values

`"34.1760212".to_f` should not be converting to 0

sample data

```
34.1760212,-116.9995880
34.1521587,-116.9844818
34.1697721,-116.9020844
34.1657952,-116.8505859
34.1521587,-116.8100739
34.1709084,-116.7949677
34.1879499,-116.8402863
34.1964693,-116.8759918
34.1947655,-116.9178772
34.1862459,-116.9508362
34.1805656,-116.9783020
34.1763052,-116.9983006
```

```rb
>> p interest.geofence.first
#=> ["34.1760212", "-116.9995880"]

>> p interest.geofence.first.first
"34.1760212"
=> "34.1760212"

>> p interest.geofence.first.first.encoding
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

>> p interest.geofence.first.first.to_f
0.0
=> 0.0

>> p interest.geofence.first.last
"-116.9995880"
=> "-116.9995880"

>> p interest.geofence.first.last.encoding
#<Encoding:UTF-8>
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

>> p interest.geofence.first.last.to_f
-116.999588
=> -116.999588

>> p '34.1760212'.bytes
[51, 52, 46, 49, 55, 54, 48, 50, 49, 50]
=> [51, 52, 46, 49, 55, 54, 48, 50, 49, 50]

>> p interest.geofence.first.first.bytes
[239, 187, 191, 51, 52, 46, 49, 55, 54, 48, 50, 49, 50]
=> [239, 187, 191, 51, 52, 46, 49, 55, 54, 48, 50, 49, 50]
>> 

>> p interest.geofence.first.first.class
String
=> String

>> p interest.geofence.first.first.method(:to_f)
#<Method: String#to_f()>
=> #<Method: String#to_f()>

>> Marshal.dump(interest.geofence.first.first)
=> "\x04\bI\"\x12\xEF\xBB\xBF34.1760212\x06:\x06ET"

>> Marshal.dump('34.1760212')
=> "\x04\bI\"\x0F34.1760212\x06:\x06ET"
```

--
i've also tried using `BidDecimal` without success, hard coded string works but I need it to be from my imported value...

```rb
>> p BigDecimal('0')
0.0
=> 0.0
>> p BigDecimal('0.9')
0.9e0
=> 0.9e0
>> p BigDecimal(interest.geofence.first.first)
ArgumentError: invalid value for BigDecimal(): "34.1760212"
    (ripl):36:in `BigDecimal'
    (ripl):36:in `<main>'
>> p BigDecimal('34.1760212')
0.341760212e2
=> 0.341760212e2
```

...
more relevant details:
here is the Mongoid model its being saved under

```rb
class Interest
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # ...

  field :name, type: String
  field :geofence, type: Array
end
```

and the import script

```rb
# ...
interest = FR::Interest.new
interest.name = place
interest.geofence = []

log :debug, tn, "importing #{filename}"
File.foreach("#{APP_ROOT}/tmp/geofences/#{filename}") do |line|
  csv_data = CSV.parse(line, col_sep: ',', headers: false)
  row = csv_data[0]
  lat = row[0]
  lon = row[1]

  interest.geofence << [lat, lon]
end

interest.save!
```

Comment: 1) how do you turn that CSV data into a `interest.geofence` object? That part is missing. 2) what is the `class` of those values? Maybe they just _look_ like strings.

Comment: its imported into mongodb (mongoid/activerecord) as an array of strings

Comment: In Ruby, `"34.1760212".to_f` returns `34.1760212` so something else must be going on. What does `interest.geofence.first.first.class` return?

Comment: returns a `String`

Comment: What does `interest.geofence.first.first.method(:to_f)` return?

Comment: `#<Method: String#to_f()>`

Comment: Let’s dig a little deeper. What does `Marshal.dump(interest.geofence.first.first)` return?

Comment: `"\x04\bI\"\x12\xEF\xBB\xBF34.1760212\x06:\x06ET"`

Comment: Oh, it’s a much more common reason. Your string starts with a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), probably from parsing the CSV.

Comment: now THAT makes sense! i'll do some hunting for how to strip it -- feel free to add it as the answer and i'll confirm in chat or on post 

Comment: Make sure to read the CSV file as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011504/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-encoded-file

Comment: `File.foreach("#{APP_ROOT}/tmp/geofences/#{filename}", encoding: 'bom|utf-8')` fixed the issue, you are welcome to add it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

@stefan figured out the issue in the comments section, so all credit goes to him

The issue came to light when running `Marshal.dump`

```rb
>> Marshal.dump(interest.geofence.first.first)
=> "\x04\bI\"\x12\xEF\xBB\xBF34.1760212\x06:\x06ET"
```

specifically the characters `\xEF\xBB\xBF` reveal that there is a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the beginning of the string, which only would have arrived there from importing my text file

to resolve, I just had to re-import my data with some encoding instructions
`encoding: 'bom|utf-8'`

```rb
File.foreach("#{APP_ROOT}/tmp/geofences/#{filename}", encoding: 'bom|utf-8') do |line|
  ## ...
end
```