# CSV.read Illegal quoting in line x

Tags: ruby, csv, formatting

I am using ruby CSV.read with massive data. From time to time the library encounters poorly formatted lines, for instance:

```
"Illegal quoting in line 53657."
```

It would be easier to ignore the line and skip it, then to go through each csv and fix the formatting. How can I do this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I had this problem in a line like `123,456,a"b"c`

The problem is the CSV parser is expecting `"`, if they appear, to entirely surround the comma-delimited text.

Solution use a quote character besides `"` that I was sure would not appear in my data:

`CSV.read(filename, :quote_char => "|")`

Comment: In the requestor's situation he specifically has massive data and just wants to skip errors. Changing the :quote_char just helped me out in my situation though.

Comment: this worked in my situation as well, it ran through 100+ thousand lines of csv data without errors

Comment: Awesomeness continues in 2015 as well :)
Thanks.. I did take like a couple of hours to reach here :)

Comment: For my data, I was unsure which characters would not appear, but it apparently works even with unprintable characters like `quote_char: "\x00"`.

Comment: If, like me, you are here because of a Google search to try and fix this error. My issue was I had a `""` in my csv file (probably from my text editor adding the addition `"`. As per Ruby docs, `CSV will always consider a double sequence of this character to be an escaped quote. This String will be transcoded into the data’s Encoding before parsing.` https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: At least in recent versions, setting the quote_char to nil should also work and is semantically more correct.

Answer (score 46):

The [`liberal_parsing`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new) option is available starting in Ruby 2.4 for cases like this. From the documentation:

> When set to a true value, CSV will attempt to parse input not conformant with RFC 4180, such as double quotes in unquoted fields.

To enable it, pass it as an option to the CSV read/parse/new methods:

```
CSV.read(filename, liberal_parsing: true)
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't let CSV both read and parse the file.

Just read the file yourself and hand each line to `CSV.parse_line`, and then `rescue` any exceptions it throws.

Answer (score 6):

Try forcing double quote character `"` as quote char:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach(file,{headers: :first_row, quote_char: "\x00"}) do |line|
  p line
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Apparently this error can also be caused by unprintable BOM characters. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543225/how-to-avoid-tripping-over-utf-8-bom-when-reading-files) suggests using a file mode to force a conversion, which is what finally worked for me.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open(@filename, 'r:bom|utf-8') do |csv|
  # do something
end
```