# Ruby unable to parse a CSV file: CSV::MalformedCSVError (Illegal quoting in line 1.)

Tags: ruby, csv, malformed

**Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

**Ruby ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]**

**Rails 3.2.9**

Following is the content of my received CSV file:

```
"date/time","settlement id","type","order id","sku","description","quantity","marketplace","fulfillment","order city","order state","order postal","product sales","shipping credits","gift wrap credits","promotional rebates","sales tax collected","selling fees","fba fees","other transaction fees","other","total"
"Mar 1, 2013 12:03:54 AM PST","5481545091","Order","108-0938567-7009852","ALS2GL36LED","Solar Two Directional 36 Bright White LED Security Flood Light with Motion Activated Sensor","1","amazon.com","Amazon","Pasadena","CA","91104-1056","43.00","3.25","0","-3.25","0","-6.45","-3.75","0","0","32.80"
```

However when I am trying to parse the CSV file I am getting error:

```
1.9.3dev :016 > options = { col_sep: ",", quote_char:'"' }
=> {:col_sep=>",", :quote_char=>"\""} 

1.9.3dev :022 > CSV.foreach("/tmp/my_data.csv", options) { |row| puts row }
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1925:in `block (2 levels) in shift'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1887:in `each'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1887:in `block in shift'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1849:in `loop'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1849:in `shift'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1791:in `each'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1208:in `block in foreach'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1354:in `open'
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1207:in `foreach'
    from (irb):22
    from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Then I tried simplifying the data i.e.

```
"name","age","email"
"jignesh","30","jignesh@example.com"
```

however still I am getting the same error:

```
      1.9.3dev :023 > CSV.foreach("/tmp/my_data.csv", options) { |row| puts row }
  CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1925:in `block (2 levels) in shift'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1887:in `each'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1887:in `block in shift'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1849:in `loop'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1849:in `shift'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1791:in `each'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1208:in `block in foreach'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1354:in `open'
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1207:in `foreach'
      from (irb):23
      from /home/jigneshgohel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-rc1/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Again I tried simplifying the data like this:

```
name,age,email
jignesh,30,jignesh@example.com
```

and it works.See the output below:

```
  1.9.3dev :024 > CSV.foreach("/tmp/my_data.csv") { |row| puts row }
  name
  age
  email
  jignesh
  30
  jignesh@example.com
   => nil
```

But I will be receiving the CSV files having quoted data so removing quotes solution is not actually I am looking for.I am unable to figure out what is causing the error: **CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1.** in my earlier examples.

I have verified that in the CSV there are no leading/trailing spaces by enabling "Show whitespace characters" and "Show Line Endings" in my text editor.Also I have verified the encoding using following.

```
  1.9.3dev :026 > File.open("/tmp/my_data.csv").read.encoding
  => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

*Note: I tried using CSV.read too but same error with that method.*

Can anybody please help me getting out of the problem and make me understand where it is going wrong?

=====================

I just found following post at: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/448070 and tried following:

```
  file_data = file.read
  file_data.gsub!('"', "'")
  arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(file_data)

  arr_of_arrs.each do |arr|
    Rails.logger.debug "=======#{arr}"
  end
```

and got the following output:

```
   =======["\xEF\xBB\xBF'date/time'", "'settlement id'", "'type'", "'order id'", "'sku'", "'description'", "'quantity'", "'marketplace'", "'fulfillment'", "'order city'", "'order state'", "'order postal'", "'product sales'", "'shipping credits'", "'gift wrap credits'", "'promotional rebates'", "'sales tax collected'", "'selling fees'", "'fba fees'", "'other transaction fees'", "'other'", "'total'"]
    =======["'Mar 1", " 2013 12:03:54 AM PST'", "'5481545091'", "'Order'", "'108-0938567-7009852'", "'ALS2GL36LED'", "'Solar Two Directional 36 Bright White LED Security Flood Light with Motion Activated Sensor'", "'1'", "'amazon.com'", "'Amazon'", "'Pasadena'", "'CA'", "'91104-1056'", "'43.00'", "'3.25'", "'0'", "'-3.25'", "'0'", "'-6.45'", "'-3.75'", "'0'", "'0'", "'32.80'"]
```

which messed up reading the data properly as the default **col_sep** used is a comma character.
However I tried using **quote_char** option like this:

```
  arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(file_data, :quote_char => "'")
```

but it ended up the following error:

```
   CSV::MalformedCSVError (Illegal quoting in line 1.):
```

Thanks,
Jignesh

Comment: Used the sample data you've provided and the parsing works fine. Not getting any `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 1` error.

Comment: In my edited section the output contains following: "\xEF\xBB\xBF'date/time'".Is it creating some problem? I don't know what does it represent.Thanks.

Comment: The Unicode characters at the start of the file are BOM (Byte Order Mark). You can try `sub!(/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/, '')` or `CSV.foreach("test.csv", encoding: "bom|utf-8")`

Comment: Thanks Anand I shall try using your encoding suggested solution.Meanwhile with my temporary solution in Edit section when used header_converters like: arr_of_arrs = CSV.parse(file_data, { col_sep: ";", headers: true, header_converters: [ :symbol ]  }) I got following error: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8).That one mentions ASCCII-8BIT as encoding.How does that encoding matters, how those BOM characters got in there? Such errors should be clearly shown in the exception thrown by library instead of finding them by chance in to_s output.

Comment: The following link http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, will help in understanding how encoding matters. As for how those BOM characters got in there, you'll need to check the origin of the CSV file received and how it was saved.

Comment: @Anand using your suggestion worked: csv_options[:encoding] = "bom|utf-8"; CSV.foreach(uploaded_file.path, csv_options) do |row| ... end; where csv_options is a Hash of options CSV.new supports.

Answer (score 35):

```
quote_chars = %w(" | ~ ^ & *)
begin
  @report = CSV.read(csv_file, headers: :first_row, quote_char: quote_chars.shift)
rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError
  quote_chars.empty? ? raise : retry 
end
```

it's not perfect but it works most of the time.

N.B. `CSV.parse` takes the same parameters as `CSV.read`, so either a file or data from memory can be used

Answer (score 25):

Anand, thank you for the encoding suggestion.  This solved the illegal quoting problem for me.

Note: If you want the iterator to skip over the header row add `headers: :first_row`, like so:

```
CSV.foreach("test.csv", encoding: "bom|utf-8", headers: :first_row)
```

Comment: Thanks! `encoding: "bom|utf-8"` is what solved my problem.

Comment: For those getting `ArgumentError: unknown encoding name - bom|utf-8` with ruby 2.4+, make sure you update the `csv` gem to version 3 or newer (`gem 'csv', '~> 3.0'` in your Gemfile).

Answer (score 14):

I just had an issue like this and discovered that CSV does not like spaces between the col-sep and the quote character. 
Once I removed those everything went fine.
So I had:

```
12,  "N",  12, "Pacific/Majuro"
```

but once I gsubed out the spaces using

```
.gsub(/,\s+\"/,',\"')
```

resulting in

```
12,"N",  12,"Pacific/Majuro"
```

everything went fine.

Comment: Note if you want to replace spaces on both sides of quoted string within comma value...gsub(/,\s+\"/,',"').gsub(/\"\s+,/,'",')

Comment: This is the second time i've had this issue and the second time i've found this answer. Unfortunately, I can't upvote it again.

Answer (score 13):

Rails 6 version, ruby 2.4+

```
CSV.foreach(file, liberal_parsing: true, headers: :first_row) do |row|
    // do whatever
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Fantastic @mArtinko5MB! liberal_parsing: `When set to a true value, CSV will attempt to parse input not conformant with RFC 4180, such as double quotes in unquoted fields.`

Answer (score 5):

from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12533730/6683147) pass the option `:quote_char => "|"`

```
CSV.read(filename, :quote_char => "|")
```

Comment:  this seems to work with the `CSV.foreach` method as well

Comment: it works, but in conjunction with headers: true or headers: :first_row it messes up the column values

Answer (score 4):

Add the `:liberal_parsing => true` argument to `CSV.read` and this should solve some of the issues with "illegal quoting"

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with the trademark character that was throwing this error.

The trademark character translates to \"! in UTF-8, so it was the open-ended quotation symbol that was throwing the error. So I did this:

`.gsub!("\"!", "")`

And then I tried creating my CSV object and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to read the file and get a string and then parse thes tring into a CSV table, but received an exception:

```
CSV.read(File.read('file.csv'), headers: true)
CSV::MalformedCSVError: Unclosed quoted field on line 1794.
```

None of the answers provided here worked for me. In fact, the one with highest votes was taking so long to parse that eventually I terminated the execution. It most likely was raising many exceptions, and that time is costly on a large file.

Even more problematic, the error is not so helpful, since it is a large CSV file. Where exactly is line 1794? I opened up the file in LibreOffice which opened without any problems. Line 1794 was the last row of data of the csv file. So apparently the problem had to do with the end of the CSV file. I decided to inspect the contents as a string with File.read. I noticed the string ended with a carriage return character:

```
,\"\"\r
```

I decided to use chomp and remove the carriage return at the end of file. Note if $/ has not been changed from the default Ruby record separator, then chomp also removes carriage return characters (that is it will remove \n, \r, and \r\n).

```
CSV.parse(File.read('file.csv' ).chomp, headers: true)
 => #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:1794>
```

And it worked. The problem was the \r character at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a line like `Agricover 22040169 Access; TonnoSport`

The trouble is the CSV parser is anticipating `"`, in the event that they seem, to completely surround the comma-delimited text.

solution use a quote person except `"` that i was certain would not appear in my records:

```
CSV.parse(file_path, headers: true, :quote_char => "|")
```

For more information read?

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#class-CSV-label-Reading

Answer (score -1):

A less common cause of this error is when the file doesn't do *any* field quoting, but `quote_char` is still set (by default it's `"`) and one or more fields happen to contain the character.

To disable field quoting entirely, set `quote_char: nil` in the parsing options.

For example, given a file `/tmp/people.csv` like this:

```
Actor,Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson,1972-05-02
Character,TV's Frank,1956-08-30
```

It could be parsed with this:

```rb
CSV.read('/tmp/people.csv', quote_char: nil)
```

Comment: As a quick follow-up, using `liberal_parsing: true` also works. Perhaps the "safer" method, of the two options, because it *should* allow for quoted values using `"` in the future.

Answer (score -4):

Try this hint:

1. Open your CSV file in a text editor
2. Select the whole file and copy it
3. Open a new text file
4. Paste the CSV data into the new file and Save the new file
5. Import your new CSV file

Comment: csv file could be in MBs, which cannot be opened like that