# Rails CSV import without double-quote hiccups

Tags: ruby, csv

I was under the assumption that by stating the `:col_sep` as, say \t

```
CSV.foreach("items.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", headers: true) do |row|
```

that columns that include double-quotes would not generate issues, yet the CSV import process still complains about `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting in line 45.`

How can this be elegantly avoided?

Answer (score 4):

Answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864064/csv-read-illegal-quoting-in-line-x).  adding a specification for quote character, in this case something non printable:

```
CSV.foreach("items.tsv", :col_sep => "\t", :quote_char => "\x00", headers: true) do |row|
```

does the trick.  So, apparently defining `col_sep` is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

From Ruby 2.4, You can pass `liberal_parsing: true` option to allow double quotes for methods such as `CSV.foreach`, `CSV.parse`, `CSV.new`.

document is here

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/CSV.html

> When set to a true value, CSV will attempt to parse input not conformant with RFC 4180, such as double quotes in unquoted fields.