# Ruby CSV incorrect first character

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

I have an xlsx file, I do the following to export it as a .csv :

- Export xlsx file as csv using excel, default encoding
- Open .csv file with notepad, save it again by specifying the encoding utf8 (notepad saves the BOM)
- Open the file with CSV.read(path_to_file)

It seems to work well, but for some reason the first header is corrupted by some unknown character (I have no idea what it is, and when I try to copy paste it it disappears, it is represented as a big white rectangle in Windows)

[image: Unknown character]

When I open my file with any text editor, there doesn't seem to be a problem

First line looks like : `Id;Type....`

In case this helps

```
csv.headers.first # => ".Id" where . is that character
csv.headers.first.first.bytes # => [239, 187, 191]
csv.headers.first.first.b # => "\xEF\xBB\xBF"
```

How do I fix that ?

Windows 10, Ruby 2.2

Comment: UTF8 with BOM, what's the problem?

Comment: This could help: [How to avoid tripping over UTF-8 BOM when reading files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/543225/477037)

Comment: How come this BOM is not detected by the CSV parser automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

That is the UTF-8 BOM.
Try setting the mode like this:

```
CSV.read(path_to_file, 'r:bom|utf-8')
```